# Calculate consecutive occurrence in a row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like below:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9bb88e4b8ac981eb9cfabb13848a79b9

The expected result is below:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=04932c1f5d6f49349a49aac63f51c78a

Here T1 is last month, T2 is last to last month, T3 is 3 months back from now and so on.

TOTAL_INACTIVITY = Total number of months where the amount is 0

MAX_CONSECUTIVE_INACTIVITY  = Maximum number of consecutive months where the amount is zero

RECENT_INACTIVITY = Maximum number of consecutive months starting from the recent month i.e T1 and going backward where the amount is 0. That means if T1 has any value except zero, RECENT_INACTIVITY  will be zero. For example, person_id 5555 has RECENT_INACTIVITY  = 4 since T1_Amount,T2_Amount,T3_Amount and T4_Amount are all 0.

NB: I have around 10 million records and looking for an optimized solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE t8_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t7_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t6_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t5_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t4_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t3_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t2_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE t1_amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS total_inactivity,
       CASE
       WHEN (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 8
       WHEN (0,0,0,0,0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 7
       WHEN (0,0,0,0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 6
       WHEN (0,0,0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount),
         (t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 5
       WHEN (0,0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount),
         (t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount),
         (t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 4
       WHEN (0,0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount, t3_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount, t4_amount),
         (t3_amount, t4_amount, t5_amount),
         (t4_amount, t5_amount, t6_amount),
         (t5_amount, t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t6_amount, t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 3
       WHEN (0,0) IN (
         (t1_amount, t2_amount),
         (t2_amount, t3_amount),
         (t3_amount, t4_amount),
         (t4_amount, t5_amount),
         (t5_amount, t6_amount),
         (t6_amount, t7_amount),
         (t7_amount, t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 2
       WHEN (0) IN (
         (t1_amount), (t2_amount), (t3_amount), (t4_amount),
         (t5_amount), (t6_amount), (t7_amount), (t8_amount)
       )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS max_consecutive_inactivity,
       CASE t1_amount WHEN 0 THEN
         1 + CASE t2_amount WHEN 0 THEN
           1 + CASE t3_amount WHEN 0 THEN
             1 + CASE t4_amount WHEN 0 THEN
               1 + CASE t5_amount WHEN 0 THEN
                 1 + CASE t6_amount WHEN 0 THEN
                   1 + CASE t7_amount WHEN 0 THEN
                     1 + CASE t8_amount WHEN 0 THEN
                       1 
                       ELSE 0
                       END
                     ELSE 0
                     END
                   ELSE 0
                   END
                 ELSE 0
                 END
               ELSE 0
               END
             ELSE 0
             END 
           ELSE 0
           END
       ELSE 0
       END AS recent_inactivity
FROM   Tran_rec t;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | PERSON_ID | T8_AMOUNT | T7_AMOUNT | T6_AMOUNT | T5_AMOUNT | T4_AMOUNT | T3_AMOUNT | T2_AMOUNT | T1_AMOUNT | TOTAL_INACTIVITY | MAX_CONSECUTIVE_INACTIVITY | RECENT_INACTIVITY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1111 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 34 | 0 | 89 | 33 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2222 | 100 | 120 | 0 | 200 | 340 | 110 | 89 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
> | 3333 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 110 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
> | 4444 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 60 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
> | 5555 | 80 | 70 | 60 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
> | 6666 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 | 40 | 0 | 50 | 4 | 2 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f7d48d5d0764d80585b54b744c5021a)*